# On expected value of $|X - Y|$ for independent and equally likely random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, both being equally likely to assume any of the values 1,2,...,$n$.

Compute $E|X-Y|$.

I have been battling with this one for a while now - I have absolutely no idea how to approach the problem.  Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A natural starting point would be to solve the problem for small $n$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the standard approach to a problem of this type. Let $f$ denote the joint density of $(X,Y)$ and $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$. From independence $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ iff $(x,y)\in S^2$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. You need to compute $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)$ which equals the sum $\sum_{(x,y)\in S^2}|x-y|f(x,y)$. To evaluate this sum, I follow @lulu's advice and solve the problem when $n$ is small.